# Does numpy methods work correctly on numbers too big to fit numpy dtypes?

Tags: python, numpy, int, precision

I would like to know if numbers bigger than what int64 or float128 can be correctly processed by numpy functions 
EDIT: numpy functions applied to numbers/python objects outside of any numpy array. Like using a np function in a list comprehension that applies to the content of a list of int128?

I can't find anything about that in their docs, but I really don't know what to think and expect. From tests, it should work but I want to be sure, and a few trivial test won't help for that. So I come here for knowledge:
If np framework is not handling such big numbers, are its functions able to deal with these anyway?

EDIT: sorry, I wasn't clear. Please see the edit above
Thanks by advance.

Comment: sorry, I meant to ask whether they work or not on python objects when these adapt to format like int128 above the limitations of numpy dtypes (like with python int that can adapt to a 128 bits format, if needed)?

Answer (score 2):

See the Extended Precision heading in the Numpy documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html). For very large numbers, you can also create an array with `dtype` set to `'object'`, which will allow you essentially to use the Numpy framework on the large numbers but with lower performance than using native types. As has been pointed out, though, this will break when you try to call a function not supported by the particular object saved in the array.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([10**105, 10**106], dtype='object')
```

But the short answer is that you you can and will get unexpected behavior when using these large numbers unless you take special care to account for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can have numpy arrays of python objects, which could be a python integer which is too big to fit in np.int64. Some of numpy's functionality will work, but many functions call underlying c code which will not work. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([123456789012345678901234567890]) # a has dtype object now
print((a*2)[0])  # Works and gives the right result
print(np.exp(a)) # Does not work, because "'int' object has no attribute 'exp'"
```

Generally, most functionality will probably be lost for your extremely large numbers. Also, as it has been pointed out, when you have an array with a dtype of np.int64 or similar, you will have overflow problems, when you increase the size of your array elements over that types limit. With numpy, you have to be careful about what your array's dtype is!

Answer (score 1):

When storing a number into a numpy array with a dtype not sufficient to store it, you will get truncation or an error

```
arr = np.empty(1, dtype=np.int64)
arr[0] = 2**65
arr
```

Gives `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`.

```
arr = np.empty(1, dtype=float16)
arr[0] = 2**64
arr
```

Gives `inf` (and no error)

```
arr[0] = 2**15 + 2
arr
```

Gives `[ 32768.]` (i.e., 2**15), so truncation occurred. It would be harder for this to happen with float128...